# Can't run my Django App server

Tags: python, django

I can't run my server for my Django app. Here's some history on what happened since the last time it worked:

My computer had some troubles, so I saved my project in a server and worked with code on server for 2 weeks to check I could develop with no problems (all went fine from start). Then I had my computer formatted, so I installed all again.

When tried to run python `manage.py runserver command`, it asked me to install all in my requirements file. I did so.

Now all requirements are installed (or at least I think so), but when running command, here's what I get:

(Yes, I tried `syncdb`)

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
django.setup()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
app_config.import_models(all_models)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/models.py", line 32, in <module>
from tastypie.compat import AUTH_USER_MODEL
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tastypie/compat.py", line 14, in <module>
User = get_user_model()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 136, in get_user_model
return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 199, in get_model
self.check_models_ready()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You install django 1.7, but you project are for oldest django version

Read [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/) about changes in new version, or switch back to oldest django.